# setStyle() function for GeoJSON features - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, features

Ok, since I already asked a very long question about this, but since it didn't get any new replies for a while, and not to get confused in details, I will keep this one simple the best way I can.

If I'm not mistaken, a `setStyle` function for a named, particular feature would be as follows:

```py
var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);

rect.setStyle({color: "#4B1BDE"});
```

...which would change the color from orange to blue. I'm also aware of the `resetStyle()` function that will revert the style to the original.

This is how I style my GeoJSON:

```py
var everything = L.geoJson(myfile, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature){
        array_of_layers.addLayer(feature);
    },
    style: function(feature){
            switch(feature.properties.name){
            case "belgium": return belgium_style; break;
            case "bosnia": return bosnia_style; break;
            case "denmark": return denmark_style; break;
            case "great_britain": return britain_style; break;
            case "greece": return greece_style; break;
            case "italy": return italy_style; break;
            case "serbia": return serbia_style; break;
            case "spain": return spain_style; break;
            }
    }

});
```

**What I want to do is to make just one country blue and the others gray, later in the code.** It's a two-step thing, to paint all countries to gray, and then make one blue.

The first thing is, I need such a loop that would iterate over each feature and `setStyle()` for all countries to gray. Does it work if I just `everything.setStyle({color: "#4B1BDE"})` or something?

The second thing is, (that's giving me sleepless nights) how do I select **just one feature** out of a group of GeoJSON polygons to work with? Just the country that I need to paint to blue.

If it was a matter of mouse hovering, I could place an event listener as are done in Leaflet tutorials. But regardless of user interaction, I want to set and reset the style by calling it with its name, as I did with the rectangle above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out leaflet's `setStyle()` function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This works  **without** needing to remove the layer and recreate a new one as described above:

```
geojson_layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {  
  if(layer.feature.properties.NAME == 'feature 1') {    
    layer.setStyle({fillColor :'blue'}) 
  }
});
```

It seems to be quite a bit more efficient than removing and recreating the geoJson layer.
From the docs, a [`GeoJSON` layer extends `FeatureGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson) which in turn extends `LayerGroup`.
Additionally, it seems that each geoJson feature has its own layer in the `FeatureGroup`!

Comment: How do I trigger this method when I want to change the style dynamically?

Comment: I think is equivalent to geojson_layer.setStyle(function...)

Comment: one problem here if you change the layers ie add child layers, they will be created from the original style in the options, not what you set it to

Answer (score 21):

I have written down a small code to style specific geojson feature using leaflet. you can try it on [JSFiddle (Original, non-functional)](http://jsfiddle.net/QAA2C/89/), [Functional JSFiddle 2018-02-17](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/m8ruvz3b/3/), or use the following code test locally.

For this example i am using us-states.json files but it can be used for any geojson file.

I hope it will help.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet Coloring Geojson Features</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<style>
#map {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}
.info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.info h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #777;
}
.legend {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
}
.legend i {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init_map();
        init_geojson();
        $("#btn").on('click', function () {
            var stateName = $('#statename').val();
            console.log(stateName);
            init_geojson(stateName);
        });
    });
    var map, geojson, sn;

    function init_map() {
        map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
        }).addTo(map);
        geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
            style: style
            //onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    function init_geojson(n) {
        console.log(geojson.options);
        map.removeLayer(geojson);
        if (n != "") {
            sn = n;
            console.log(sn);
            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    }

    function style(feature) {
        console.log(sn);
        if (sn == feature.properties.name) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                fillColor: '#ff0000'
            };
        } else {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                fillColor: '#666666'
            };
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="statename" value="Alaska">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Set Color"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, it was all about making a `style(feature)` function checking over the `feature.properties.name` value. Thanks!

Comment: @DorukKarınca Yes :)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: I see you created the function style(feature) but I can't see where you applied it to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as a secondary answer because this question kept coming up while trying to articulate my problem into a Google search.

Basically I had an `L.LayerGroup` composed of several `L.Layer` objects which were made form GeoJSONs. The features in these layers were visualized as `L.CircleMarker` objects already. I wanted to make it so that I could modify the properties of the underlying features in the layer in a sidebar and have those changes reflected in the layer immediately by changing their colour.

Since everything was a bunch of `L.Layer` objects inside an `L.LayerGroup` objects however, I could not set the style on the `L.LayerGroup` directly, and so I had to go one level deeper:

```
var buildingCircleMarkerStyle = function(propertyName) {
    switch (propertyName) {
        case 'A':
            return {radius: 8, fillColor: "#cc9200", color: "#000000", weight: 1, opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 1}
        case 'B':
            return {radius: 8, fillColor: "#a0f545", color: "#000000", weight: 1, opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 1}
        default:
            return {radius: 4, fillColor: "#888888", color: "#000000", weight: 1, opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 1}
    }
}

var buildingMarker = function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, buildingCircleMarkerStyle(feature.properties["buildingProperty"]))
}
buildingLayerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.eachLayer(function (subLayer) {
        console.log(subLayer);
        subLayer.setStyle(buildingCircleMarkerStyle(subLayer.feature.properties["buildingProperty"]));
})
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it seems to work for my purposes.